# Error in retrieval of data from multiple tables based on joins

Tags: mysql

> I have following query which is not working it gives following error

## 1054 - Unknown column 'league_members.l_id' in 'on clause'

**SQLQuery**

```
SELECT bhk.u_manager, leaderboard.total_pts 
from bhk LEFT JOIN leaderboard on bhk.u_id=leaderboard.u_id and league_members.l_id=1;
```

Comment: The query doesn’t have any reference to league_members before that so it can’t know where that columns comes from

Comment: How to add reference to that as if i add league_members after from it also gives error.

Comment: You’ll need to explain what exactly you are trying to do, how that table relates to this etc.

Comment: That's a very clear error message - the table league members is not invoked anywhere. You could improve this question be describing what you are trying to achieve, the tables involved and their relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will need a double **SQL JOIN**, as well as a **condition**.

Since you are using three tables :

- bhk ;
- leaderboard ;
- league_members.

Your query should look like this :

```
    SELECT bhk.u_manager, leaderboard.total_pts
    FROM bhk
    LEFT JOIN leaderboard ON bhk.u_id=leaderboard.u_id
    LEFT JOIN league_members ON league_members.l_id = **LINK TO OTHER TABLE ID**
    WHERE league_members.l_id=1;
```

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included table  `league_members` in FROM clause and referring it's column.

Maybe you meant this:

```
SELECT bhk.u_manager, leaderboard.total_pts 
from bhk LEFT JOIN leaderboard 
on bhk.u_id=leaderboard.u_id 
LEFT JOIN league_members ON leaderboard.u_id  = league_members.l_id
WHERE league_members.l_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution

```
SELECT bhk.u_manager,leaderboard.total_pts from bhk,league_members LEFT JOIN leaderboard on league_members.u_id=leaderboard.u_id where bhk.u_id=league_members.u_id and league_members.l_id=1
```